# Simple search form query on rails model not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on my first search form to query Bboy model. Input parameter in search field is name attribute of Bboy model. I want to display search results in a table as below.

This is my search form code:

```
<%= form_tag( :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:name], placeholder: "Search Bboys" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

This in my Bboy model:

```
def self.search(name)
 where('name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%")
end
```

This is SearchController.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
def index
@bboy = Bboy.search(params[:name])
end

end
```

This is in search/index.html.erb search results:

```
<h1> Here are your search results: </h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Crew</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Foundation</th>
      <th>Originality</th>
      <th>Dynamics</th>
      <th>Execution</th>
      <th>Battle</th>
      <th>User Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @bboy.each do |bboy| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= bboy.name %></td>
        <td><%= bboy.crew %></td>
        <td><%= bboy.country %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "foundation" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "originality" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "dynamics" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "execution" %></td>
        <td><%= rating_for bboy, "battle" %></td>
        <td><%= Rate.raters_count(bboy.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', bboy %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bboy_path(bboy) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', bboy, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<% end%>
```

Comment: ActionController::ParameterMissing in BboysController#create param not found: bboy
Extracted source (around line #74):

72
73
74
75
76
          

 

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def bboy_params
params.require(:bboy).permit(:avatar, :name, :crew, :country)
end
end

Comment: too many doubts.. permit attributes first, `form_tag` to create action?, write a custom action like `search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search form is submitting data in `text_field_tag :search`
and in your controller you are taking data from `params[:name]` it should be `params[:search]`
check your params after form submission in controller action

Answer (score 0):

You are using form_tag so you need to provide url as well, your form_tag should hit index action not create

```
form_tag( :method => "get", url: searches_path , id: "search-form", )
```